# Taking manipulated data out of the R console and creating a csv

Tags: r

I have used R to remove duplicates from a csv file using the following (`lda_data` is my csv file name)

```
unique(lda_data[duplicated(lda_data),])
```

This works great, however I need to get the results from the console into another csv file.

What are the methods of getting manipulated data from a csv file into another new and manipulated csv file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Anyway the answer is `write.csv(your_data, "your_data.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `write.csv` command:

```
write.csv(dataframe, "/path/filename.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, I'm aware of this and have tried it before, however unless i'm missing something it just re-creates the original csv file, without any of the changes made in the console.

Comment: In that case, save your manipulated data to a new (or the same) data frame: `newdata <- unique(lda_data[duplicate(lda_data),]` and use `newdata` in the `write.csv()` command